# Sequelize: select models with a given number of matching children

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

In my schema, `User` hasMany `GameSession`, `GameSession` hasMany `Game`.

For a particular user, I'm trying to select the most recent game session which has three games, each of which has a non-null score.

[This comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1668#issuecomment-41006938) looks like it does almost exactly what I want, but it's not working for me. It suggests this code:

```
ModelA.findAll({
  include: [ModelB],
  having: 'count(ModelB.id) > 0'
});
```

I think the above comment might be out of date, because unless I wrap the `having` clause in an array I get `Error: where: "raw query" has been removed, please use where ["raw query", [replacements]]`.

So I have this JS:

```
user.getGameSessions({
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Game,
      where: {
        score: {
          $ne: null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  having: ['count(Games.id) = 3'],
  order: [['updatedAt', 'DESC']],
  limit: 1
}).then(function(gameSessions) {
  res.json(gameSessions);
});
```

And this is the query it is making:

```
SELECT
  `GameSession`.*,
  `Games`.`id` AS `Games.id`,
  ...
  FROM (
    SELECT
      `GameSession`.`id`,
      ...
      `GameSession`.`UserId`
    FROM `GameSessions` AS `GameSession`
    WHERE `GameSession`.`UserId` = 33 AND (
      SELECT `GameSessionId`
      FROM `Games` AS `Game`
      WHERE (
        `Game`.`GameSessionId` = `GameSession`.`id`
        AND `Game`.`score` IS NOT NULL
      )
      LIMIT 1
    ) IS NOT NULL
    HAVING count(Games.id) = 3
    ORDER BY `GameSession`.`updatedAt` DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS `GameSession`
  INNER JOIN `Games` AS `Games`
  ON `GameSession`.`id` = `Games`.`GameSessionId`
  AND `Games`.`score` IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY `GameSession`.`updatedAt` DESC;
```

But running this gives the following error: `SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Games.id' in 'having clause'`. I've also tried using singular `Game.id` in the `having` clause, since I'm not always certain when to use the plural and when to use the singular, and I get a similar error.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think because MySQL is case sensitive your `Games.id` is `Games.Id` or `Games.ID`.

If I were you to save yourself some grief in the future, just make every table and column uppercase or all lower case.  Don't do camel casing or things like that!  It becomes really hard to debug.

So your code here is probably:

```
having: 'count(Games.id) = 3',
```

should be:

```
having: 'count(Games.Id) = 3',
```

Edit:

Have you tried putting backticks around your count?  Like this:

```
having: 'count(`Games`.`id`) = 3',
```

Comment: Afraid not. The column is `id`, in lowercase, and it seems through experimentation that it's not case sensitive when it comes to the column names anyway, at least in the collation my tables are in.

Comment: hrmm bummer!  I thought I nailed it.  Can You post your model and associations?

Comment: I honestly don't think they'd help much. There's nothing special in them. Each has an `id`, and the relations are as I described in the question. Foreign key names etc are default.

Comment: Actually I just updated my answer, see if putting backticks in the having clause works.

Comment: I had tried that, yeah. Just tried it again to see the error message, and the error message doesn't change at all. It still actually says `Unknown column 'Games.id' in 'having clause'`. But I can verify that the backticks were added to the query itself: `...IS NOT NULL HAVING count(\`Games\`.\`id\`) = 3 ORDER BY...`

Comment: I'm starting to have the feeling that this is a bug in Sequelize. I'm hoping one of the developers pops a head in here.

Comment: Hrmm weird, yeah I spent some time googling this because it seems so weird.  I came across a lot of people that were saying sub-queries are buggy with Sequelize, so that could be what is going on.  You could always just use your own SQL statements for things like this.  sorry I couldn't be more helpful, should I delete this answer?

Comment: No, I think the suggestions were all valid.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Is it possible to limit an include?](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2017)**
>
> Currently no. I think there's a feature request open
>   for it (although i couldn't find it with a cursory search. It's not
>   trivial to implement since it requires a join on a subquery.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant. I'm not trying to limit the child models (`Game`), only the parent (`GameSession`). The `limit` key in my options object isn't within `include`.